# Google Composer- How do I install Microsoft SQL Server ODBC drivers on environments

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am new to GCP and Airflow and am trying to run my python pipelines via a simple PYODBC connection via python 3. However, I believe I have found what I need to install on the machines [Microsoft doc]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017 , but I am not sure where to go in GCP to run these commands. I have gone down several deep holes looking for answers, but don't know how to solve the problem

Here is the error I keep seeing when I upload the DAG:

[Airflow Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfaZq.png)

Here is the PYODBC connection:

```
pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft SQL Server};SERVER=servername;DATABASE=dbname;UID=username;PWD=password')
```

When I open my gcloud shell in environments and run Microsoft downloads it just aborts, when I downloaded SDK and connected to project from local download it auto aborts or doesn't recognize commands from Microsoft. Can anyone give some simple instruction on where to start and what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you take a look at this page? https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/connection/odbc.html

Comment: @rmesteves Thanks for posting, I have seen this too. I think I am embarrassingly a few steps before this where I am struggling to identify the cmd line interface with GCP that will install the drivers for airflow. I have accessed via kubernetes cluster "connect" cmd line, but it says all changes are ephemeral when i run commands. So I am just lost on where I need to go to make necessary installs or run commands

Answer (score 7):

It's Simple ! No Need of DockerFile, KubernetesPodOperator, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, etc just a basic **python operator** will do

**Points to consider**

- GCP Composer Worker's Pod image is ubuntu 1604 (just run a basic python operator with a command os.system('cat /etc/os-release') to check )
- It has unixodbc-dev already installed on the worker's pod image
- Composer creates the bucket and mount it with airflow
- So why not just install the pyodbc from pypi packages and provide the mssql odbc driver as paramter in pyodbc connection method

here 'gs://bucket_created_by_composer' == '/home/airflow/gcs'

```
gcs bucket created by composer ->
          -> data/
          -> dags/
```

**Step By Step Approach**

**Step 1:** Install pyodbc, mssql odbc on any ubuntu instances to get the driver files

for consideration lets do it on GCP VM Intance with ubuntu 1804 image

```
#update the packages
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get update -y
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list
sudo apt-get update -y
echo Installing mssql-tools and unixODBC developer...
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools unixodbc-dev
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install  -y mssql-tools #it includes sql_cmd and bcp (we dont need those)
sudo apt install python3-pip #installing pip3
pip3 install pyodbc
```

**Step 2:** Get the Driver Files and upload it to the data folder of gcs_bucket created by the  composer

```
cd /opt/microsoft
#now you can see there is one directory 'msodbcsql17', version may change
#we need to upload this directory to the data folder of gcs_bucket

#for this you may choose which ever approach suits you
#copying the directory to /<home/user> for proper zipping/uploading to gcs
cp -r msodbcsql17 /home/<user> #you may need to use sudo 
#upload this /home/<user>/msodbcsql17 to any gcs_bucket 
gsutil cp -r /home/<user>/msodbcsql17 gs://<your-gcs-bucket>
```

download this folder from gcs bucket to local and the upload this folder to data folder of gcs bucket created by composer

*choose any approach/method, main aim is to get the msodbcsql17 folder in the data folder of gcs bucket created by composer*

**Final structure:**

```
gcs bucket created by composer ->
          -> data/msodbcsql17/
          -> dags/<your_dags.py>
```

**Step 3:** using this msodbcsql17 drivers for pyodbc connection

**EXAMPLE DAG:**

```
import os
import time
import datetime
import argparse
import json
from airflow import DAG
import airflow

from airflow.operators import python_operator


default_dag_args = {
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(0), #
    'provide_context': True
}



dag = DAG(
        'pyodbc_test',
        schedule_interval=None, #change for composer
        default_args=default_dag_args
        )


def check_connection(**kwargs):
    print('hello')
    driver='/home/airflow/gcs/data/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.5.so.2.1'
    #this is the main driver file, the exact location can be found on gcs_bucket/data folder or check the /etc/odbcinst.in file of ubuntu instance in which you installed the pyodbc earlier

    def tconnection(ServerIp,LoginName,Password,mssql_portno):
        """ A method which return connection object"""
        import pyodbc
        pyodbc.pooling = False 
        try:   
            sql_conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={4};SERVER={0},{1};UID={2};PWD={3}".format(ServerIp,mssql_portno,LoginName,Password,driver)) 
        except pyodbc.Error as ex:
            sqlstate = ex.args[1]
            raise


        return sql_conn

    con=tconnection('<your-server-ip>','<your-login-name>','<your-password>','1433')
    #recommendation is to take the password and login from airflow connections
    import pandas as pd
    q='select * from <your-db-name>.<your-schema-name>.<your-table-name>'
    df=pd.read_sql(q,con)
    print(df)

Tcheck_connection= python_operator.PythonOperator(
        task_id='Tcheck_connection',
        python_callable=check_connection,
        dag=dag ) 


#calling the task sequence
Tcheck_connection
```

**PYPI Packages**

```
pyodbc
pandas
```

Have tested on Composer recently

Comment: Tested on composer image-version=composer-1.10.4-airflow-1.10.6, I was able to install pyodbc through pypi packages, so it had unixodbc-dev

Comment: You don't have a find or create an Ubuntu 18.04 vm.  You can run steps 1 and 2 of the commands in a BashOperator in a DAG.
Tested on composer-1.15.2-airflow-1.10.14

Answer (score 1):

Consider that Composer is a Google managed implementation of Apache Airflow hence, expect it to behave differently.

Having this in mind, [custom Python dependincies and binary dependencies not available in the Cloud Composer worker image](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/using-kubernetes-pod-operator#top_of_page) can use the `KubernetesPodOperator` option.

What this does essentially, is to allow you to [create a custom container image](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/) with all your requirements, push it into a container image repository (Dockerhub, GCR) and then pull it into your Composer environment, so all of your dependencies are met.

This escalates better as there is no need for you to interact with the machines (this approach is stated in your original question), and it looks easier to just build your container image with whatever you need in there.

Specifically speaking of `pyodbc` and in this context of dependency installation using Composer, [there is a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138863630) to address this issue, that also outlines a workaround (basically what is mentioned in this answer). You might want to check it out.

Comment: I'm gonna second this answer since `KubernetesPodOperator` will be better fit for this type of use case.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Composer currently primarily supports installing PyPI packages written in pure Python. Installing system packages is not fully supported at this time, but there are some workarounds (such as setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and uploading shared libraries, etc). You're getting aborts because you installed the Python part of the package, but not system dependencies the Python package depends on.

As you read, changes to Airflow workers in Composer are ephemeral (or at least, should be treated as such), but one way of working around this is to install packages using `BashOperator` *before* the task that needs the library runs. It's not pretty, but it ensure that dependencies are installed on the worker before the Python code that needs them is called.

Comment: Thanks for response. I think my greatest concern is scalability of something like this as well as time of execution. It seems over complicated for something as simple as connecting to a SQL server instance to push/pull data. There has to be a better solution with a feature rich big data platform like airflow

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. The first solution which worked for me was building a docker image that would install the drivers and then run the code. 
Initially I tried to find a way of installing the drivers on the cluster but after many failures I read in documentation that the airflow image in composer is curated by Google and no changes affecting the image are allowable. So here is my docker file:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim-buster
#FROM gcr.io/data-development-254912/gcp_bi_baseimage 
#FROM gcp_bi_baseimage
LABEL maintainer = " " 
ENV APP_HOME /app 
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY / ./
# install nano 
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends \
        apt-utils \
        apt-transport-https \
        curl \
        gnupg \
        unixodbc-dev \ 
        gcc \
        g++ \ 
        nano \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends msodbcsql17 \
    && apt-get install libgssapi-krb5-2 \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && rm -rf /tmp/*
 RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 CMD ["python","app.py"]
```

requirements.txt:

```
pyodbc==4.0.28
google-cloud-bigquery==1.24.0    
google-cloud-storage==1.26.0
```

You should be good from this point on.

Since then I managed to set up an Airflow named connection to our sql server and am using mssql_operator or mssql_hook. I had worked with a cloud engineer to set up the networking just right. What I found is that the named connection is much easier to use, yet kubernetesPodOperator is still much more reliable.