# Cloud Composer worker fails to connect to external database

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-composer, pymssql

I am attempting to take my existing cloud composer environment and connect to a remote SQL database (Azure SQL). I've been banging at my head at this for a few days and I'm hoping someone can point out where my problem lies.

Following the documentation found [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-kubernetes-engine#proxy-with-workload-identity) I've spun up a GKE Service and SQL Proxy workload. I then created a new airflow connection as show here using the full name of the service azure-sqlproxy-service:

[image]

I test run one of my DAG tasks and get the following:

> Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist

Not sure on the issue I decide to remote directly into one of the workers, whitelist that IP on the remote DB firewall, and try to connect to the server. With no command line MSSQL client installed I launch python on the worker and attempt to connect to the database with the following:

```
connection = pymssql.connect(host='database.url.net',user='sa',password='password',database='database')
```

From which I get the same error above with both the Service and the remote IP entered in as host. Even ignoring the service/proxy shouldn't this airflow worker be able to reach the remote database? I can ping websites but checking the remote logs the DB doesn't show any failed logins. With the generic error and not many ideas on what to do next I'm stuck. A few google results have suggested switching libraries but I'm not quite sure how, or if I even need to, within airflow.

What troubleshooting steps could I take next to get at least a single worker communicating to the DB before moving on the the service/proxy?

Comment: Have you tried to open up TCP/IP access for your local SQL server? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348255.

Comment: Yep, confirmed with nmap I can see server and port is open:1433/tcp open  ms-sql-s

Answer (score 0):

After much pain I've found that Cloud composer uses ubuntu 1804 which currently breaks pymssql as per here:

https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/687

I tried downgrading to 2.1.4 to no success. Needing to get this done I've followed the instructions outlined in this post to use pyodbc.

[Google Composer- How do I install Microsoft SQL Server ODBC drivers on environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60346440/google-composer-how-do-i-install-microsoft-sql-server-odbc-drivers-on-environme)